# Matlab: How to fit a state space model to data with nlinfit

Tags: matlab, model, state, space

I've run an experiment and would like to fit a state space model to the data. Unfortunately I have little experience with how to implement this, so was hoping to ask for some help.

In the experiment participants reach towards different targets. The participant receives feedback about their movement via an on screen cursor. This cursor displays their reaching movement, but is rotated by 30 degrees. This means participants initially make large errors, but reduce them with repeated practice.

The following data provides some illustrative results. Each value represents an 'epoch' (average of eight trials):

> 18.26
>   13.95
>   10.92
>   10.32
>   8.23
>   6.57
>   7.05
>   5.98
>   5.99
>   4.58
>   4.35
>   3.72
>   3.71
>   3.04
>   4.47
>   4.16

I have found a paper that has used a similar experiment and has fit a state space model to their data. The model is composed of two equations:

> 1)  e(n) = p(n) - s(n) + E(n) 2)  s(N+1) = s(n) + Ae(n)
>
> Where  e(n) = error on trial n (i.e. values above) 
>   p(n) = perturbation applied to movement (i.e. 30 degrees) 
>   s(n) = internal state of system
>   E(n) = noise 
>   A    = rate of adaptation to perturbation

The paper indicates that they used the nlinfit matlab function to implement this model, but I don't understand how I would do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen your post now, ages later, but I've come accross it while looking for a problem of my own.

From experience, I know that if you have a system that you want to obtain a State Space model for, and you have measured inputs and corresponding measured outputs from your system, you can use the 'pem' function that will build you a state space model based on your measurements.

The 'pem' function is part of the system identification toolbox.